# Есть ли речевые ошибки в предложениях?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, деепричастия, тавтология

> Находясь вместе, они сияли, выделяясь из толпы.
>
> Вода смыла сады и урожаи

Есть ли речевые ошибки в этих предложениях?

Comment: Пожалуйста, создайте для каждого предложения отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении можно увидеть такой правдоподобный смысл: оказываясь вместе, двое влюблённых восторженно улыбались друг дружке (*сияли*); находясь в толпе, они этим из неё *выделялись*. Если именно такой  смысл пытались передать, ошибок нет.

Во втором предложении вырисовывается излишне апокалиптичная картина: после страшного цунами из почвы с корнями вымыло и унесло куда-то деревья в садах и повсеместно то, что росло на полях. Если же речь о простом наводнении, да ещё об урожае с тех самых деревьев, которые "смыло" (ср. "сняв голову и волосы") то всё - сплошная речевая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Находясь вместе, они сияли, выделяясь из толпы.**

СИЯТЬ 3. Блестеть, светиться от радости, счастья и т.п.

Речевых ошибок нет, два деепричастных оборота являются разными обстоятельствами: времени (когда находились...) и следствия (и поэтому выделялись...).

2) **Вода смыла сады и урожаи**

Лучше сказать так: **Вода смыла сады (= деревья в садах) и урожаи с полей (то, что росло на полях).** Это уже предложенный вариант.

Здесь использован **художественный прием метонимии**, то есть перенос наименования с одного предмета на другой по смежности. Сравнить: Догорал камин (= дрова в камине).

Смысл у предложения такой: вода повредила деревья в садах и всё, что росло на полях. Поэтому слово *поля* желательно применить, к тому же слово ***урожай*** имеет общее значение (плоды, овощи, зерновые) и обычно используется не одно, а с каким-нибудь  определением.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Находясь вместе, они сияли, выделяясь из толпы.

Не нахожу здесь речевых ошибок.

> 2. Вода смыла сады и урожаи.

Что такое урожай?

> [УРОЖАЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%F3%F0%EE%E6%E0%E9), -я; м. 1. Количество уродившихся злаков, плодов, трав и т.п. Обильный, средний у. Виды на у. Хороший у. ягод. Неважный у. на свёклу. Убирать у. Пшеница нового урожая. 2. Разг. Об очень большом количестве злаков, плодов, трав, уродившихся в этом году. Нынче у нас у. Бог послал у. 3. на кого-что. Разг. Об изобилии, множестве чего-л. в какой-л. момент, в какое-л. время. В этом году у. на журналы. Нынче у. на невест. У. на поэтов. <Урожайный (см.).

Из этого определения следует, что без дополнительных слов нельзя сводить УРОЖАЙ только к зерновым, он включает в себя и то, что растет на деревьях. Поэтому я вижу здесь речевую ошибку.

Для сравнения: "Вода смыла сады и урожаи с полей". Здесь ошибки нет. Хотя смытые водой плодовые деревья — картина действительно страшная.

Comment: В садах могли быть одни декоративные деревья, что отправляет за "урожаями" (в значении 2) на подразумеваемые поля.

Comment: Ну если так...Но кому придет в голову без дополнительных пояснений или контекста, что сады в данном предложении — декоративные?

Comment: Я это в том смысле, что абсолютной ошибки нет (при верной грамматике можно приписать правдоподобный смысл и вписать хоть в какой-то воображаемый контекст), многое зависит от того, что _пытались_ сказать.